# "close other sessions" button

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I want to add a "close other active sessions" button to my PHP web app.

I'm thinking of tracking (userid,sessionid,expiration) on a MySQL table and kill the sessions the following way:

```
$currentsessionid=session_id();
foreach($othersessions as $session){
    sessionid($session['sessionid']);
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE userid = $currentuserid AND sessionid <> $currentsessionid");
session_id($currentsessionid);
session_start();
```

<strike>The table would also be updated after each session_start() if the user is logged, removing expired entries.</strike>

Expired entries are removed every time a user logs in.

Is this the proper approach? Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe the language API should provide a method to track all the existing sessions on the server-side

Comment: Using `DELETE` only let you know the last time the user logged in, what if you want to have a history of logging?

Comment: @theMarceloR: Surprisingly I believe it doesn't, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @EmCo: Interesting idea, I'll consider implementing session history (with some more info like ip and date/time) on another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP the sessions are normally isolated. You need to create your own session handler and write session (plus some extra tracking information) into the database so this become more easy to manage.

For example, like you have in your question, the `userid`. You then can search for sessions of a specific user.

Another field you should have is a timestamp so that you can let sessions expire, e.g. if older than X hours, you throw them away.

You can - if you like - also take a look if a user has got an existing session and import the old session. However this can have security implications. You need to think about what happens when an attacker logs on instead of the real user.

Can an attacker even throw the valid user out of the system then? That should be prevented.

Also take into consideration that you can take over the session data of a previous session under a new session ID. That is similar to [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id), a login should always regenerate the session id, as well as the logout and other, important steps (e.g. re-authentication before changing the email-address).

Comment: Well, the timestamp is the field expiration I mentioned, and reauth when changing the password or email is already implemented of course. Also a new login only happens after a logout (which calls session_destroy()) or a new session, since calling the login function when the user is already authenticated throws an exception, so always a new login will receive a new sessionid. I guess I'm on the right track, then. Thanks for the input.